# Tutorials: package format 2 vs format 1

Tags: ros, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I was running through the tutorial "CreatingMsgAndSrv", I ran into problems when trying to use

> rosmsg show beginner_tutorials/Num

The terminal displayed a long error with

> The manifest (with format version 2) must not contain the following tags: run_depend

This sounded strange, as the tutorial had just told me to add the lines with `run_depend`.
After searching a bit, I found [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/migrating_from_format_1.html) or [here (mirror)](http://mirror-eu.docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/migrating_from_format_1.html), that the `run_depend` tag is deprecated in format 2, and was only used in format 1.

This mistake also is introduced in the "CreatingPackage" tutorial. Should the tutorials maybe mention something about the two different versions, similar to the rosbuild/catkin differences?

Could somebody advise as to where I should report this mistake, or how I can help to get it updated?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274199/tutorials:-package-format-2-vs-format-1/) by [flurin4](https://answers.ros.org/users/32403/flurin4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-10-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-10-26**:
You link also uses the docs for ROS Jade which is EOL for a while. You might want to look at the docs for an active ROS distro.

**Comment by [flurin4](https://answers.ros.org/users/32403/flurin4/) on 2017-10-26**:
Actually the links I added were for finding where the problem lies. The errors were in the normal Tutorials =)
I saw you already updated most of it, but could you also update the code generated from the GitHub project? It's still in parts 6.1.4 and 6.1.5 of the "CreatingPackage" tutorial

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-10-26**:
I already updated that code with the PR to `catkin_tutorials`. The wiki is just still using a cached version of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Format 2 package manifests should indeed not use `run_depend`, but `exec_depend` (depending on what the `run_depend` was for).

I believe this discrepancy between what the tutorial tells you and `catkin_create_pkg` does was introduced in [ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg#191](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/pull/191): "catkin_create_pkg use package.xml format 2". That PR made `catkin_create_pkg` start using format 2, but apparently the submitter did not update the tutorials to match.

As the ROS wiki is just that, a wiki, you could register for an account and then fix the tutorial(s). That would be very much appreciated.

I've commented on PR 191 ([here](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/pull/191#issuecomment-339702786)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flurin4](https://answers.ros.org/users/32403/flurin4/) on 2017-10-26**:
Thanks for the feedback!
I'll see whether I manage to update the wiki with the new format version.

In some cases I used `exec_depend`, while in others I directly went for `depend`, as the same dependencies were both required during build as runtime.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-26**:
Fast turn-around: @Dirk Thomas fixed the tutorials as well as the code examples ([comment](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/pull/191#issuecomment-339714398)).